# Add multiple columns to dataframe base on regular expression (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add all the columns from my dataframe "rdi_data" with the text "RDI" in the column to my other dataframe "data".

```
# first I copy all the dates from the date column
rdi_data["Date"] = data["Date"]
# now I want to copy all the columns with 'RDI' in it
rdi_data.insert(data.filter(regex='RDI'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share a sample input with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: IIUC `rdi_data = data.filter(regex=('RDI|Date'))`

Comment: what does "'RDI' in it" mean? 'RDI' in the name of column or 'RDI' being one of the values in the column?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression.

```
rdi_columns = [c for c in data.columns if "RDI" in c]
rdi_data[rdi_columns] = data[rdi_columns]
```

Comment: I only have the column names then, how can i get the values to my new dataframe?